# Transparent displays that allow UV light/sunlight to pass through them?

Tags: light, display, resolution, uv

Is there a type of digital display that can work to let sun through it, so that the dark pixels block the UV, and transparent pixels let the UV through?
I'm aware of monochrome LCDs for a resin printers, but I don't know if the LCD can be used with a UV-A sunlight source.

Comment: Do you want it to *only* block UVA, or is it fine if it blocks visible light too?

Comment: Its fine if it blocks visible light too.

Comment: In that case I imagine a standard LCD would work, there's not much different between UVA and visible light that would make it not work. It'd be harder if we were talking UVB or UVC, but UVA should act pretty much like visible light for the most part.

Comment: Google told me UV light damages LCD's, is this only after a long time? Also would the black pixels fully block out the UV?

Comment: UVA is low enough in energy that I wouldn't expect it to damage it very fast. And no, but only to the extent that they don't fully block out visible light either.

Comment: Thanks. And are LCD's the only type of display that would work for UV to pass through?

Comment: They're the only display technology I know of that work transmissively; most other displays are either reflective (electrophoretic displays) or emissive (OLED, VFD, CRT, etc). There's no apostrophe in LCDs, by the way.

Comment: Whoops haha!  Alright LCDs it is. I found a thread that helps describe the process im after: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395760/uv-light-masking-and-lcd-screens

Comment: I also imagine the only way to emit a digital UV image is with a UV projector, is this correct?

Comment: Aren't you talking about using LCDs with UV though? Couldn't you just use that with a UV lamp as the backlight?

Comment: Yes, just checking to see all the options.

Comment: Another other method is DLP  (Digital Light Processing), which is basically an array of electrostatically actuated micromirrors. It works fine with UV and relatively high intensities. The cost is higher though.  There may also be some distortion from the optics.

Comment: FYI, some kinds of 3D printers use a UV light source with an LCD in order to harden resin in layers to build up the model being printed.

Comment: Are there others other than those two options, 3d resin printers, and DLP projectors?